# Node.js and Johnny-Five "document is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, johnny-five

I am using Node.js and Johnny-Five with an Arduino Uno micro controller. My goal is to, upon pressing the button hooked up to the Arduino, the webpage will display a count of the number of times it has been pressed in the form of a bar.

In console I get an error when I press the button that says "document is not defined" and references my variable that is supposed to change the css styling:

```
var bar1 = document.getElementById('bar1');
```

Not sure why that is giving an error. Any thoughts? Below is my javascript:

```
var five = require("johnny-five"),
  bumper, led, counter, toggleState;
  toggleState = false;

five.Board().on("ready", function() {

  bumper = new five.Button(7);
  led = new five.Led(13);
  counter = 200;

  bumper.on("hit", function() {

    led.on();
    console.log( "Button has been pressed" );
            counter += 10; //add 10 everytime the button is pressed

            console.log(counter);
            toggleState = true;
            console.log("on");

    //function increaseBarSize () {
    if(toggleState == true) {
        var bar1 = document.getElementById('bar1');
        bar1.style.width = counter;
        console.log(bar1);
    }

    }).on("release", function() {
        led.off();
        console.log("off");

    });

    });
```

Comment: You're trying to run DOM code inside a nodejs file?  DOM code needs to run in a script tag in a web page (in the browser), not in your nodejs program.  It appears that maybe you don't really understand the separation between front-end code and back-end code.

Comment: I am relatively new to javascript and coding in general - having just started a few months ago, so its all part of the learning process. Is manipulating the DOM based on Arduino sensor input an impossible task? I have received another recommendation to use Socket.io in order to get this to work. Is this viable?

Comment: The first thing you need to understand is that a web page has a front-end piece that is HTML and javascript that runs in the browser and a back-end piece that runs on your server (which I assume is nodejs and is maybe running on your Arduino device).  These are two completely separate pieces of code that run in separate places.  The server creates a web page which is delivered to the browser and then the web page runs in the browser.  The DOM is ONLY in the browser.  You do not manipulate the DOM in nodejs or on your Arduino.  You only manipulate the DOM from javascript within the web page.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because there isn't DOM on the server side, you need to send this value and manage the DOM at the client side.

Try this:

**SERVER SIDE**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
var five = require("johnny-five"),
bumper, led, counter, toggleState;
toggleState = false;
five.Board().on("ready", function() {

    bumper = new five.Button(7);
    led = new five.Led(13);
    counter = 200;

    bumper.on("hit", function() {

        led.on();
        console.log( "Button has been pressed" );
        counter += 10; //add 10 everytime the button is pressed

        console.log(counter);
        toggleState = true;
        console.log("on");

        //function increaseBarSize () {
        if(toggleState == true) {
            io.on('connection', function(socket){
              socket.emit('counter', counter);
            });
        }

    }).on("release", function() {
        led.off();
        console.log("off");

    });
});
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/<client page>.html'); //change <client page> to the client document
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
 var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
 var bar1 = document.getElementById('bar1');
 socket.on('counter', function(counter){
     bar1.style.width = counter;
 });
 <script>
```

***NOTE***: assume that you already installed Socket.io and express modules.